# Set up a cronjob to run every N days with a specific date as a start

Tags: shell, curl, cron

I need to set up a cronjob, which will run every 5 days, but I need it to start at a specific date.

For example, it will execute a curl every 5 days, but i want the first execution to be next week.

Is this possible or should I wait for the day to come and set it up then?

Comment: I'd add the cron when the time comes

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704927/does-cron-expression-in-unix-linux-allow-specifying-exact-start-and-end-dates

Answer (score 1):

Some `cron` implementations may offer you a `*/5` syntax for the day, or even an e.g. `16-31/5` syntax meaning "every 5 days starting from the 16th".

The first problem is that you will need a second `*/5` entry for the next months. The second problem with such a syntax, is that your script will trigger on the 1st, 6th, 11th, 16th, 21th, 26th and 31st of each month. These fixed days are not generally what one means with "once every 5 days".

Your solution is to trigger your job every day with `cron` (possibly starting with the first day of your choice) and to do a preliminary calculation in your script to figure out if you are the first day of your 5 days period. If not, you end your script immediately with an `exit 0`.

This test may be as simple as (in `bash`):

```
(( $(date +"%j") % 5 == 0 )) || exit 0
```

Note that, with such a line, the script will execute if the day of the year is a multiple of 5. As for `*/5` in `crontab` this may not be once every 5 days when the year changes, but it's a pretty good approximation. You have the idea, you may do better.

[update] This of course can be added to the command executed by cron:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
mn h * * * (( $(date +"%j") % 5 == 0 )) && my_command
```

Comment: I was thinking to do something like that, but I wanted to avoid a cron which executes every day with a code logic in the script.

Comment: @Frozkata This logic can be moved to the cron command. If you want some specific solutions to be avoided, then you should state it clearly in your question, we are not mind readers.