# How to schedule a firebase function, in limited times

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a firebase function that should be ran every 1 hour, but only for X times.
I scheduled it in this way :

```
functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 hour').onRun((context) => {
    let counter = // read last counter value from db
    counter++;
    if(counter === X)
        return;
    // save counter in db

    // my job
}
```

But this method is not optimal, because the scheduler is always active, even when it's not required. Do you offer a better method for this purpose?

Comment: Since Cloud Functions uses Cron format, can't you use something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704927/does-cron-expression-in-unix-linux-allow-specifying-exact-start-and-end-dates

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't supported by scheduled functions.  What you'll have to do is schedule future invocations of the function with [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) with the specific schedule you want.  A complete list of instructions to do this is too long for Stack Overflow, but you can [read this blog post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a) to learn how to programmatically schedule future invocations of a Cloud Function.