# How to create a PubSub function that triggers after onWrite function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I wan to create a `pubsub` function after a `function.firestore.onWrite` function is triggered, since this last one contains the cron to be specified in the `pubsub.schedule(cron).onRun(=>{})`

What will be the correct way to wait for the `cron time` to be created and "deploy" the `pubsub function` afterwards?, so is created once the cron is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  Pubsub triggers do not allow for one-time future units of work to be scheduled at a specific moment in time.  They only allows you to set a single schedule strictly adhered to at the time the function was published.

If you want to schedule a single unit of work in the future, you should use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) for that.  It can be instructed to trigger an HTTP function at a future time you choose.

See also:

- [How to schedule a firebase function, in limited times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60401784/how-to-schedule-a-firebase-function-in-limited-times)
- [Cloud Functions for Firebase trigger on time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time)
- https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's customary to upvote and mark helpful answers as correct using the buttons to the left of the answer.